# Check Differences between two Tables with allowed nulls in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-update

I have two different tables, Table1 & Table2 each with their own sets of values. I want to check a column to see if there are any differences from each other and `UPDATE` Table1 accordingly. I have this query that updates every row regardless if they differ in the value I'm checking for:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET value = t2.value
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2
ON t1.ID = t2.ID
```

I tried using `WHERE t1.value <> t2.value` but since either `t1` and `t2` can be null, the function does not work properly. I want a query that only checks and updates where their values `t1` and `t2` are different.

Comment: So if one side is NULL and the other side is NOT NULL, I assume you want these returned, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
...
WHERE t1.value <> t2.value
OR (t1.value IS NULL AND t2.value IS NOT NULL)
OR (t1.value IS NOT NULL AND t2.value IS NULL);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just tack on `where t1.id is not null and t2.ID is not null`

eg:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET value = t2.value
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2
ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE t1.value <> t2.value
AND t1.id is not null 
AND t2.ID is not null
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you can list the conditions where you want to do the update in a `where` clause:

```
UPDATE Table1
    SET value = t2.value
    FROM Table1 t1 INNER JOIN
         Table2 t2
         ON t1.ID = t2.ID
   WHERE (table1.value <> t2.value) or
         (table1.value is null and table2.value is not null) or
         (table1.value is not null and table2.value is null)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using coalesce to provide a default value for your nulls?  Change your where clause like so.

```
WHERE COALESCE(t1.value,'') <> COALESCE(t2.value,'')
```